# Log4net - CAN'T WRITE

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a problem to use my log4net config in my programm. I use this config in a other programm and it was great !

I don't understand why he don't write.

That's my config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileRolling" />
    </root>
    <appender name="FileRolling" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="D:\Historique\historique_CNC.csv" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
      <LockModel type = "log4net.Appender.FileAppender + MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

In my assembly, I write this :

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

When My WindowsForm is called, I creat my Log :

```
public partial class MainVisu : Form
{
    public FocasCommHist CallPrg;
    public static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public MainVisu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CallPrg = new FocasCommHist();
    }
}
```

In my programm, I use my Log4net like this :

```
    // Test LOG4net
    MainVisu.log.Info(DateTimeExe);
```

Thank's for helping !

Comment: The [fine manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug) covers troubleshooting log4net itself. As an initial guess, ditch the `assembly` attribute and explicitly call `XmlConfigurator.Configure` in your `Main` instead (not your form's constructor -- the actual `Main`). Using the attributes for initialization is a bad idea; they make the moment of initialization non-deterministic and will make troubleshooting essentially impossible if, for whatever reason, they're not getting read.

Comment: That works well ! Thank you